# jquery img tag getting removed after it is added using append

Tags: jquery, append, image

On my website I tried to append my image using ("#report-type").append($img) where img is a jquery object with a src website included, based upon a drop down menu selection changing the src of the img.  I know that it actually appends in the right place, the img tag is properly formatted, and that the image shows up if i just hardcode the img tag into the HTML.

however, what happens is the page runs, and I see in firebug that the img is appended for a split second and then it disappears. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

here is my function for the dropdown change handler:

```
    $(".update-report").click(function () {
        var src, image, $img2, val;

        //Clear old charts
        //$("#report-type option").children().remove();

        //alert(typeof $("select option:selected").val());

        val = $("select option:selected").val();
        switch (val[0]) {
            case "0":
                src = "https://graphite.admarketplace.net:2222/render/?from=-7days&width=1400&height=420&_salt=1309990757.707&target=alias(movingAverage(divideSeries(sumSeries(*.server.xml.*.revenue)%2CsumSeries(*.server.xml.*.clicks)),200),%22CPC%22)&fgcolor=black&bgcolor=white&title=Average%20CPC%20per%20minute%20-%207%20Days&hideLegend=true";

                $("#chart1").attr('src',src);
                break;

            case "1":
                alert("here1");
                src = "http://graphite.admarketplace.net:2222/render/?from=-30days&width=1400&height=420&_salt=1309990757.707&target=alias(movingAverage(divideSeries(sumSeries(*.server.xml.*.revenue)%2CsumSeries(*.server.xml.*.clicks)),200),%22CPC%22)&fgcolor=black&bgcolor=white&title=Average%20CPC%20per%20minute%20-%2030%20Days&hideLegend=true";
                $img = createImg(src);
                alert(typeof $img);
                $("#report-type").append($img);
                break;

            case "2":
                alert("here2");
                src = "http://graphite.admarketplace.net:2222/render/?from=-1hour&width=1000&height=400&_salt=1309980469.069&target=alias(e.network.lb.xml.AverageRespTime,%22East%22)&target=alias(w.network.lb.xml.AverageRespTime,%22West%22)&yMax=500&fgcolor=black&bgcolor=white&title=Average%20Response%20Time%20in%20milliseconds%20Current%20Hour";
                $img = createImg(src);
                src = "http://graphite.admarketplace.net:2222/render/?from=-25hour&until=-24hour&width=1000&height=400&_salt=1309980469.069&target=alias(e.network.lb.xml.AverageRespTime,%22East%22)&target=alias(w.network.lb.xml.AverageRespTime,%22West%22)&yMax=500&fgcolor=black&bgcolor=white&title=Average%20Response%20Time%20in%20milliseconds%20Current%20Hour%20Yesterday";
                $img2 = createImg(src);

                $(".grid 16").append($img);
                $(".grid 16").append($img2);
                break;

            case "3":
                alert("here3");
                src = "http://graphite.admarketplace.net:2222/render/?from=-1day&width=1000&height=400&_salt=1309980469.069&target=alias(movingAverage(e.network.lb.xml.AverageRespTime,20),%22East%22)&target=alias(movingAverage(w.network.lb.xml.AverageRespTime,20),%22West%22)&yMax=500&fgcolor=black&bgcolor=white&title=Average%20Response%20Time%20in%20milliseconds%20Current%2024%20Hours";
                $img = createImg(src);
                src = "http://graphite.admarketplace.net:2222/render/?from=-2day&until=-1day&width=1000&height=400&_salt=1309980469.069&target=alias(movingAverage(e.network.lb.xml.AverageRespTime,20),%22East%22)&target=alias(movingAverage(w.network.lb.xml.AverageRespTime,20),%22West%22)&yMax=500&fgcolor=black&bgcolor=white&title=Average%20Response%20Time%20in%20milliseconds%20Yesterday";
                $img2 = createImg(src);

                $(".grid 16").append($img);
                $(".grid 16").append($img2);
                break;
                default:
                    alert("in the default");
        }
    });
```

Just pay attention to case 0 here because I've been fooling around trying to get this to work. This does not work either, even when I hardcode an img tag into the HTML and ONLY try and change the src.  However when I try and append the whole image this doesn't work either.

Comment: i think we might need to see a bit more code.   can we see where $img is initialized?   Can you edit your question and include the entire event handler that this is occuring in?

is this reproduce-able in other browsers?

Comment: I would assume that you're image tag is improperly formatted.  That's why the browser doesn't render it.

Comment: if I am in firebug, I can actually set a breakpoint where the img is added and it will stay there. So it doesn't have anything to do with how it is formatted. Maybe there is another script running that is automatically changing this? If this is the case, how could I sniff it out it might even possibly be back-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting you have some kind of adblocker which removes the image since the src is admarketplace...

We once spent an evening on a similar problem with a "banner.jpg" image :)

Comment: +1, for having felt the pain .. :) to @Evan, if the same happens at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/UcQ4G/ (*which works*) then it definitely is what Andy says..